# how to get the value from the array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a two dimensional array like this:

```
void getC(int **p)
{
   *p = &c[0][0];
}

int c[10][10];

int *a;

getC(a);

a[0][0];

it says error: no match for 'operator[]' in `a[0][0];` what is the problem and how to fix it?
```

Comment: You aren't passing a 2d array to getC.  Did you mean int **a?

Comment: what is this? where's actual code?

Comment: @Nirk I do mean int *a;

Comment: you're losing the information that the pointer is pointing to a 2-dim array, by just addressing it as an int-ptr.  See my sample below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you are sort of downgrading the array/pointer from an `int (*)[10]` (pointer to array of 10 int) to a simple `int pointer`, by just returning the address of the first element of the 2dim array.  While this is techically correct (the address of one element of the 2dim array is of course an int*), the information about the structure/layout of the ints in the array is lost, so the resulting a-ptr doesn't now anything about the fact that the int was part of a [10][10] structure.

In your case, the only way to get to the array elements would be to multiply your way through the int arrays, based on your own knowledge that at address a there are 100 ints organized 10x10:

```
   int *a;
   getC(&a);
   ...= a[10*x + y];  // equivalent of   c[x][y];
```

.

However, essentially, the correct way (completely preserving types) would be

```
int c[10][10];

void getC(int (**p)[10])  // pointer to pointer to array of 10 ints 
{
   *p = c;  // c itself can seamlessly change into a pointer to one sub-element 
            // (i.e. pointer to array of 10)
}

int main()
{
    int (*a)[10]; // pointer to array(s) of 10 ints
    int q;

    getC(&a);


    q= a[9][9];
        ...
}
```

The same again with one more dimension level (probably the most intutive solution):

However, essentially, the correct way (completely preserving types) would be

```
int c[10][10];

void getC(int (**p)[10][10])  // pointer to pointer to array of 10x10 ints 
{
   *p = &c;  // &c can seamlessly change into a pointer to 10x10 ints
}

int main()
{
    int (*a)[10][10]; // pointer to array(s) of 10x10 ints
    int q;

    getC(&a);  // pass adress of pointer to 10x10 ints


    q= (*a)[9][9];  // need *a in brackets to derference the pointer (operator precedence)
        ...
}
```

Comment: ok, thank you, but when we declare the void getC(int (**p)[10]), should we must specify as: int (**p)[10]? can we declare it as:getC(int **p)?

Comment: if you declare it as 'int **p' you can only pass an 'int **': e.g. int *a; getC(&a).  And with that 'a' you cannot access values with two dimensions.  The first gray box in my answer is the way to access the array members then (as one-dimensional).  The only alternative would involve wild typecasting of the parameter.

Answer (score 5):

1. You're compiling a C program with a C++ compiler.  Watch out!
2. You need to put the definition of `c` above the `getC` function (or provide a forward declaration).
3. You have statements outside of a function, which isn't allowed in C.  Wrap the `int *a` and subsequent lines with `int main(void) { ... }`
4. You need a `&` to make your `getC()` call legal - you're passing an `int *`, but it expects `int **`:

   ```
   getC(&a);
   ```
5. The statement `a[0][0]` has no effect, and is anyway wrong since `a` is just an `int *`; you can't dereference it twice.

You should probably get a beginner C book and start working through it.

Comment: yes, it should pass as getC(&a);, but how to get the value using pointer a?

Comment: Then you probably want a pointer to an array, not a simple `int *` pointer.